# Bootstrap: Responsive Footer Elements Word Wrapping

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries, responsive

I'm trying to make a responsive footer with elements that **adjust their wrappings according to the different screen-sizes**. I tried the grids of Bootstrap *col-md-x* *col-sm-x* but didn't work as expected.

Media queries seem to do the trick!

https://jsfiddle.net/wzyo53mL/

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row footer-row">
      <ul class="footer-icons list-unstyled list-inline">
        <li class="footer-container">
          <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> : 11223344
        </li>
        <li class="footer-container">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i> : facebookherehere
        </li>
        <li class="footer-container">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope-open-o"></i> : support@support.com
        </li>
        <li class="footer-container">
          <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>: <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam in id illum debitis omnis sed? </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The word wrapping works fine for small screen-sizes but it turns out a bit awful for large screen-size. Is there a way I could **get the last element to align with the previous ones**?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your trying to do but i guess try adding `vertical-align:top;` to`.footer-container:last-child span`

Comment: Ooohh. Right! I haven't tried that yet. Thanks mate! Sorry for my English. What I'm trying to describe is the word-wrapping of the last element that is looking a bit messy.

Comment: I actually want the wrapped text to be vertically positioned in the middle so that its center is aligned with the `fa fa-map-marker` icon. Sorry. Am I making any sense?

Comment: Yes on that span maybe add `vertical-align: middle;` if that is what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Yup! It worked! Thanks a ton, mate!